# Java download causes lag spike with really small files

Tags: java

EDIT: I've decided to remove the Minecraft tag. While this IS a Minecraft mod's code, the code I'm having trouble with has to do with functions within core Java, and not anything in Minecraft itself.

So, I posted a question last night about me writing a function of a Minecraft mod to allow us to implement our own capes and thanks to some of you I was able to get that working. I've crammed down the code from there and found a way to make it as small as possible while producing the same outcome. I've also found out how to read files directly from a download stream instead of copying the file. Great? Well, no. Now that I'm able to properly test everything and read my files, I've run into another problem. While everything works fine, it causes a lag spike of upwards to 2-4 seconds whenever my code is running. I've looked around and found issues about slow downloads, but nothing about the application completely freezing for a small period of time. Since this is run whenever a player first appears on-screen, this can get repetitive. I'm trying to fix the code and have rearranged it countless times in different ways and it just won't go away.

Here's the code. In short, it checks if the player has an official Mojang cape on their account. If they don't, then instead it runs my code to check if they have one of our custom capes, and exactly when this is run, is when the game has a lag spike. Note that if the player has a cape from Mojang my code is never run and I've tried disabling my code and just running the code that downloads their Mojang cape for use, so I know that part doesn't cause lag, it's specifically just my code. Even if they don't have a custom cape under my code it always causes lag. I can't think of why; the files are very small!
... While writing this, I decided to test something, and so I disabled the player.cloakUrl variable setting lines in my getCustomCapes method. Surely enough the lag still happened so I reckon the lag is caused by the lines that check if the player UUID matches one in the downloaded .txt files. I'm confident the lines of code that check and download from the .txt files are the culprits to the lag here. Note that I'm reading from streamed online files rather than saving them to the computer permanently since they don't need to. They're read every time this code is called and it needs to stay that way.

Without further ado here's the code.

EDIT: I've tried to add .close() commands to the streams with no success.

```java
    public static void getSkin(final GameProfile profile, EntityPlayer player) {
        final Map<Type, MinecraftProfileTexture> map = Maps.<Type, MinecraftProfileTexture>newHashMap();

    //  (Here's where some skin-related code would be but I cut it out for easier reading, 
    //  it has nothing to do with this situation so don't worry about that.)

         if (map.containsKey(Type.CAPE))
         {
             MinecraftProfileTexture texture = (MinecraftProfileTexture)map.get(Type.CAPE);
             player.cloakUrl = texture.getUrl();
             return;
         } else {
             getCustomCapes(profile, player); //Commenting this fixes the lag, proving it's my code that causes it.
         }
     }

    public static void getCustomCapes(final GameProfile profile, EntityPlayer player) {
        InputStream staff;
        InputStream contest;

        try {
            contest = new URL("https://www.dropbox.com/s/kvvkfk6emms3qg5/contest.txt?dl=1").openStream();
            StringWriter contestUUIDs = new StringWriter();
            IOUtils.copy(contest, contestUUIDs, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

            if (contestUUIDs.toString().contains(profile.getId().toString()))
            {
                player.cloakUrl = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/a4d3agty57sd4a8/contest.png?dl=1";
                // Commenting out the above line doesn't seem to help any, as stated before.
                return;
            }

            staff = new URL("https://www.dropbox.com/s/q6f4729i2zu02nz/staff.txt?dl=1").openStream();
            StringWriter staffUUIDs = new StringWriter();
            IOUtils.copy(staff, staffUUIDs, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

            if (staffUUIDs.toString().contains(profile.getId().toString()))
            {
                player.cloakUrl = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/42jn5r7fs6k5f4l/staff.png?dl=1";
                // Commenting out the above line doesn't seem to help any, as stated before.
                return;
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Don't make capes. Mojang has said that [capes are theirs](https://help.mojang.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1590522-minecraft-commercial-use). Make any kind of cosmetic you want as long as it isn't a cape.

Comment: The terms say I cannot SELL capes. I am not selling them, I am giving them away for free to certain players, my staff, and the players who win my contests. Nothing is being sold here, and there is no commercial use going on here.

Comment: I don’t know much about Minecraft mods but based on the behavior your seeing the UI thread tied to your code. You should run your download in another thread so you don’t block the main thread.

Comment: Minecraft only runs on one thread, I don't think I could open another one to do that unless opening a thread is simple.

Comment: In essence creating a thread is simple, however dealing with multiple threads and an existing application is not quite so straightforward.

Comment: I see. I'm not sure how Minecraft would react to another thread, being single-thread. I really do not want to break anything from other mods or the game itself by accident. Is there another way?

Comment: If the contents of file _staff.txt_, that you are downloading from the Internet, does not change, then I suggest caching the contents after you read it the first time. Indeed, you could download the file during the game initialization (if there is such a thing, I am not familiar with _minecraft_). In any case, downloading a text file from the Internet, even if it is only less than 10 lines, will take some time. Have you considered using [HttpClient](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html) instead of (Apache Commons) `IOUtils` class?

Comment: No, is HttpClient faster?

Also, downloading it during initialisation is totally possible. The only drawback I can think of that would be that to see cape updates they'd have to restart their game, but I'll definitely consider doing that.

Comment: _is HttpClient faster?_ There's one way to find out :-)

Comment: You're right. I ought to try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What an old thread, huh? So, after getting a little more experience I decided to head back to this to say I've found the solution. Here's how I fixed it: Thread magic! ug_ suggested this to me a while ago it seems, but I simply didn't understand at the time. I used some methods to start a thread with special variables that set the player's properties when it's done, removing the lag. Also, I rewrote the way the cape .txts work to be a little more efficient. You may notice there's one file now, and that one controls everything instead of each list having its own file. Here's my code. First, the above get skin methods have been scraped out almost entirely, and I added a new one since creating a GameProfile sends requests to Mojang's API, causing a little bit of lag, so I made it so this thread can also generate profiles:

```
public static void getSkin(final GameProfile profile, EntityPlayer player) {
        ThreadFetchSkins skinThread = new ThreadFetchSkins();
        skinThread.start(player, profile, mc);
 }

public static void getSkinFromUUIDAndName(UUID uuid, String username, EntityPlayer player) {
        ThreadFetchSkins skinThread = new ThreadFetchSkins();
        skinThread.start(uuid, username, player, mc);
}
```

And then, here's the thread.

```
public class ThreadFetchSkins extends Thread {

    public static TreeMap<UUID, String> customCapes = new TreeMap<UUID, String>();
    private EntityPlayer thePlayer;
    private GameProfile theProfile;
    private Minecraft mc;
    
    private boolean createProfile = false;
    private UUID id;
    private String name;
    
    public ThreadFetchSkins() {
        setName("Cape data download thread");
        setDaemon(true);
    }
    
    public void run() {
        if(createProfile) {
            theProfile = new GameProfile(id, name);
        }
        final Map<Type, MinecraftProfileTexture> map = Maps.<Type, MinecraftProfileTexture>newHashMap();
        theProfile.getProperties().clear();
        theProfile.getProperties().putAll(SkinManager.getProfileProperties(theProfile));
        map.putAll(mc.sessionService.getTextures(theProfile, false));
        
        //Removed "secure" textures grab
    
     if (map.containsKey(Type.SKIN))
     {
         MinecraftProfileTexture texture = (MinecraftProfileTexture)map.get(Type.SKIN);
         thePlayer.skinUrl = texture.getUrl();
         String grab = texture.getMetadata("model");
         // Currently returns null for steve skin
         thePlayer.modelAlex = !(grab == null);
         thePlayer.worldObj.obtainEntitySkin(thePlayer);
     }

     if (map.containsKey(Type.CAPE))
     {
         MinecraftProfileTexture texture = (MinecraftProfileTexture)map.get(Type.CAPE);
         thePlayer.cloakUrl = texture.getUrl();
         thePlayer.worldObj.obtainEntitySkin(thePlayer);
     }
     else {
         grabCustomCapes();
     }
    }

    public void grabCustomCapes() {
        try {
            URL capeDownload = new URL("https://www.dropbox.com/s/q6f4729i2zu02nz/capes.txt?dl=1");
            String capeFolder = Minecraft.getMinecraftDir().getPath() + "/NFCCapes";
            FileUtils.forceMkdir(new File(capeFolder));
            FileUtils.copyURLToFile(capeDownload, new File(capeFolder + "/capes.txt"));
            InputStream fileOS = new FileInputStream(capeFolder + "/capes.txt");
            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileOS));
            
            String line = buf.readLine();
            customCapes.clear();
            while(line != null) {
                String[] data = line.split(";");
                customCapes.put(UUID.fromString(data[1]), data[2]);
                line = buf.readLine();
            }
            fileOS.close();
            FileUtils.getFile(capeFolder).delete();
            
            if(customCapes.get(theProfile.getId()) != null) {
                thePlayer.cloakUrl = customCapes.get(theProfile.getId());
                thePlayer.worldObj.obtainEntitySkin(thePlayer);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }
    
    public void start(EntityPlayer player, final GameProfile profile, Minecraft minecraft) {
        thePlayer = player;
        theProfile = profile;
        mc = minecraft;
        super.start();
    }
    
    public void start(UUID uuid, String username, EntityPlayer player, Minecraft minecraft) {
        id = uuid;
        name = username;
        thePlayer = player;
        mc = minecraft;
        createProfile = true;
        super.start();
    }
}
```